# How to fire a command when a shell script is interrupted?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, interrupt-handling

I want to fire a command like " `rm -rf /etc/XXX.pid`"  when the shell script is interrupted in the middle of its execution. Like using `CTRL+C`
Can anyone help me what to do here?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Although it may come as a shock to many, you can use the `bash` built-in `trap` to trap signals :-)

Well, at least those that *can* be trapped, but `CTRL-C` is usually tied to the `INT` signal (it can be changed with `stty` but let's discount that possibility for simplicity).

You can therefore trap the signals and execute arbitrary code. For example, the following script will ask you to enter some text then echo it back to you. If perchance, you generate an `INT` signal, it simply growls at you and exits:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

exitfn () {
  trap SIGINT            # Restore signal handling for SIGINT.
  echo; echo 'Aarghh!!'  # Growl at user,
  exit                   #   then exit script.
}

trap "exitfn" INT        # Set SIGINT trap to call function.

read -p "What? "         # Ask user for input,
echo "You said: $REPLY"  #   then echo back.

trap SIGINT              # Restore signal handling.
```

A test run transcript follows (a fully entered line, a line with pressing `CTRL-C` before any entry, and a line with partial entry before pressing `CTRL-C`):

```bash
pax> ./testprog.sh 
What? hello there
You said: hello there

pax> ./testprog.sh 
What? ^C
Aarghh!!

pax> ./qq.sh
What? incomplete line being entere... ^C
Aarghh!!
```

Comment: How to get the function to be called whatever provoked the script to end, instead of just `^c` ?

Comment: @MUYBelgium, that should be asked as a question, not raised as a comment. But you can trap on `EXIT` to execute code when shell exits.

Comment: Is it _necessary_ to manually restore `trap SIGINT` before the script ends ? What happens if I forget it somewhere ?

Comment: @Estecka: it's good practice to clean up after yourself, though I believe the trap belongs to the current shell process (the shell running the script) so will automatically disappear when the shell exits. That means it could, for example, be an issue if you `source` the script rather than running it in a separate process.

Answer (score 3):

`trap` is used to catch signals in scripts, including the `SIGINT` generated when Ctrl-C is pressed.

Comment: +1 This is much better, I was about to suggest a logical operator to chain scripts.