# Script starts when another one is killed

Tags: python, linux, sh

Imagine we have two scripts: **A.py** (which is currently running) and **B.py** (which is not running)

Is there a way that when we kill **A.py** (by doing CTRL-C or `kill -9 PID_A.py`), the script **B.py** starts automatically?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Not really, no. You can have a watchdog process look at the process listing and do things when some specific processes change state, but that's clearly not a turnkey solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fire a command when a shell script is interrupted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702148/how-to-fire-a-command-when-a-shell-script-is-interrupted)

Comment: Control-C sends `SIGINT` to every process in the foreground group, which may include both `A.py` and `B.py`, and `kill -9` should *not* be used in normal operation. You probably want to create a single program (a shell script would suffice) that runs `A.py` followed by `B.py`, such that *it* runs `A.py` and blocks until `A.py` exits, at which point *it* continues by running `B.py`.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I will try these solutions